Are Jesus’s words in Matt. 24:28 parabolic, idiomatic, or prophetic/literal?
If you read the account of Armageddon in Rev. 16:17-19:21 you see that it is the literal fulfillment of Jesus’s prophecy of bodies and vultures in Matt. 24:28.

Welcome to BH. Do read the Tour [below, left] to see how this site works.

This is a duplicate question. including whether it is parabolic, idiomatic etc:  Meaning of "Where there is a dead body, there the vultures will gather.". Dr. Bill, may I suggest that since you see a fulfillment of the prophecy in Rev. 16, you add an answer to the original version of the question? Being a clear duplicate, this version will probably be closed.

Matthew 24:28 is an idiom that conveys the idea that one can anticipate events by observing certain phenomena. Although one may not see a body lying low on the ground, but the presence of vultures in the sky suggests the existence of a dead body. This metaphorical expression encourages vigilance and awareness.
In Matthew 24:3, the disciples asked Jesus about the signs of His coming and the end of the age. Jesus' response emphasized the need to remain vigilant and watchful. By paying attention to observe certain phenomena, they can foresee the consequences in advance.
Regarding the connection between Matthew 24:28 and Revelation 16:17-19:21, it is quite uncertain. Revelation 16:17 describes the pouring out of the seventh bowl, signaling the culmination of the End Times. At this point, the window for vigilance has already passed.
